# multiple transition animations for an activity

Tags: android

I have 3 activities -
Activity A, Activity B and Activity C. the transitions are as follows

A->B and B->A , A->C and C->A

now, when I am returning to A, I need different animation for the transition, depending on whether I am coming from B or C.

Activity A is the home page of the app, so I am going from A->B or A->C using Textviews but from both of them, I am returning to A using the hardware back button.

So, my question is how can I detect in A, whether I am returning from A or B and apply the transition animation accordingly?

Comment: how to apply single animation, that I know.

Comment: here  is some help to get results from activtiy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result

Answer (score 0):

use a static variable integer type, when you satart activity B set the integer value 1, when you start C set value 2. and check every time in OnResum() the value of Integer.

Comment: As you know that  `OnResum()` is not good point to set these kind of variables as it often called when some dialog comes in front of some activity.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `startActivityForResult` method as it is more clean and reliable way.